App Store Rejection Due to Guideline 5.1.2 - Issues with AdMob Consent and Tracking Permissions in Flutter App
I recently published my Flutter app in the App Store, and it was initially accepted. The app included AdMob consent forms and ad codes, but I hadn't connected AdMob to my app in the AdMob dashboard during the first review. This likely caused the GDPR consent form to not display, allowing the app to pass the initial review.
However, my app update was rejected due to Guideline 5.1.2 - Legal - Privacy - Data Use and Sharing. Here's the screenshot of the rejection notice, highlighting the issue with the consent form.


I'm unsure how to proceed and need some guidance. Specifically, I'm confused about the correct approach for handling consent forms and tracking permissions. Here are my questions and understandings:

Should I display Apple's Tracking permission dialog first, and only if the user allows tracking, show the GDPR Consent Form? If the user doesn't allow tracking, should I skip the consent form and use non-personalized ads?
Alternatively, should I skip showing any consent form and only display Apple's Tracking Permission dialog? If the user allows it, show personalized ads; if not, show non-personalized ads?

I assume the first approach is correct. To implement this, I've added the following:
In pubspec.yaml:
permission_handler: ^11.3.0

In info.plist:
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your description for why you need the tracking permission</string>

In my Dart file:
Future<void> _requestTrackingPermission() async {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    var status = await Permission.appTrackingTransparency.status;
    print('Current tracking status: $status');
    if (status == PermissionStatus.denied || status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      status = await Permission.appTrackingTransparency.request();
    }
    setState(() {
      _isTrackingPermissionGranted = status == PermissionStatus.granted;
    });
    _storeTrackingPermissionStatus(_isTrackingPermissionGranted);

    if (_isTrackingPermissionGranted) {
      await _requestAndShowConsentForm();
    } else {
      _storeConsentStatus(ConsentStatus.unknown);
      _loadNonPersonalizedAds();
    }
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await _requestAndShowConsentForm();
  }
}

Future<void> _storeTrackingPermissionStatus(bool isGranted) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('tracking_permission_granted', isGranted);
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _initializeMobileAds();
  _requestTrackingPermission();
  _loadItems();
  _loadDarkModePreference();
  _loadLocalePreference();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    await _showAppOpenAd();
  });
}

When I run this on an iOS device, I see in the console:
Current tracking status: PermissionStatus.denied
or
Current tracking status: PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied
After researching, I saw that if the current tracking status is PermissionStatus.denied, the user has previously denied the permission request. The user must be guided to the app settings to manually enable tracking permissions.
I added these codes:
Future<void> _openAppSettings() async {
  bool opened = await openAppSettings();
  if (!opened) {
    print("Failed to open app settings.");
  }
}

And updated _requestTrackingPermission:
Future<void> _requestTrackingPermission() async {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    var status = await Permission.appTrackingTransparency.status;
    print('Current tracking status: $status');
    if (status == PermissionStatus.denied || status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      bool userConfirmed = await _showPermissionDialog();
      if (userConfirmed) {
        await _openAppSettings();
      }
    } else if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      status = await Permission.appTrackingTransparency.request();
    }
    setState(() {
      _isTrackingPermissionGranted = status == PermissionStatus.granted;
    });
    _storeTrackingPermissionStatus(_isTrackingPermissionGranted);

    if (_isTrackingPermissionGranted) {
      await _requestAndShowConsentForm();
    } else {
      _storeConsentStatus(ConsentStatus.unknown);
      _loadNonPersonalizedAds();
    }
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await _requestAndShowConsentForm();
  }
}

Future<bool> _showPermissionDialog() async {
  return showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Tracking Permission Required'),
        content: Text('This app requires tracking permission to show personalized ads. Please enable it in the app settings.'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            },
            child: Text('Cancel'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
            child: Text('Open Settings'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ) ?? false;
}

I see the "Permission Denied - Open Settings" dialog, but when I go to settings, there is no option for tracking. I also checked Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Tracking and my app is not listed there.


What's my mistake here? Is my approach about showing the consent form after allowing tracking correct, if so what is my mistake in codes or am I completely wrong?
Thank you for your help!

The dialog is referring to "device settings", not your app settings. Under privacy in settings users can set a default of asking apps not to track. If this setting is on then the ask to track dialog is not shown. Tracking is just denied.

UPDATE
Yes, my approach is correct. If you want to use AdMob ads with GDPR Consent Form in iOS, you need to show Tracking Transparency dialog first, then you can show consent form. And to fix showing Tracking Transparency dialog, I used permission_handler package earlier and I believe that was the problem. I changed the package to this: app_tracking_transparency and that solved my problem. Then I updated my app and it's accepted.

I've been doing it the opposite way for nearly a year now, admob GDPR consent form first then ATT after. The apple review team are useless here too, they wern't even aware admob had a GDPR consent form when i first started using this, pretty embarrassing conversion to have with them
